# htaccess URL rewrite pattern

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an url like `http://www.abcdef.com/news_single.php?newsid=10`

With url rewriting through the htaccess I could achieve that `http://www.abcdef.com/news/10` rewrites the url to the one mentioned above. I achieved that with

`RewriteRule    ^news/([0-9]+)/?$    news_single.php?newsid=$1    [NC,L]`

Now my aim is to get a url like `http://www.abcdef.com/news/This-is-the-first-news-1`. So the newsid is at the end of the url after the last `-` and the headline is in front.

How can I tell the htaccess to ignore the title and only take attention to the number after the last `-`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tweak your regex to grab only last number after `-`:

```
RewriteRule ^news/.+?-(\d+)/?$ news_single.php?newsid=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for :) Can u just tell me one more thing: What does `QSA` do?

Comment: `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves **existing** query parameters while adding a new one.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I will accept the answer in 10 minutes, just have to wait